# How to export html table to excel using jquery which works in IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, export-to-excel

I want to export html table to excel using jquery.

```
 var htmls = "";
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
        var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'; 
        var base64 = function(s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        };

        var format = function(s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        };

        htmls = $('#divId').html();

        var ctx = {
            worksheet : 'Worksheet',
            table : htmls
        }


        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "export.xls";
        link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        link.click();
```

The above code is working fine in chrome but not in IE. Please guide me how to export the table to excel in both chrome in IE. lot of the articles are working in chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What behaviour do you get in IE? What version of IE? Does the F12 window give any clues

Comment: Am using IE11, It is not giving any error in IE just excuting the code. getting link.href value "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,%0A%20%20% somevalue" nothing is happening. In chrome if i excute this after link.click() excel file is getting downloded.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the F12 debugger? I probably can't help with your actual problem but I can help you isolate the issue more precisely.

Comment: yes i stepped through the code in IE f12 debugger. Not getting any error.

Comment: So they work identically (variables are populated as expected), but in chrome `link.click();` generates a download but IE does not? Perhaps you could edit your original question and add this information.

Comment: Looking at this.... what does the click event return?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536363(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I debug the code using f12 in IE it showing link.click() is undefined in add watch.

Comment: OK now we start narrowing it down. I though that would have shown an error in the F12 console window. I don't really have any more ideas except that the IE doco says it returns something and the W3C doco says it doesnt